# How can I have a dynamic link that takes me to an info page for the specific link selected?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, express

So, I've got a page that displays a list of users and I would like to have each of them link to a page that displays just the details for that specific user. I am very new to all of this so I'm not really sure where to start but what I think I want is for the link to change to include the specific user ID associated with the user and then I can parse that url on the backend and give send the userdetails page just the information it needs. I've got all of the user info in a mongodb collection called usercollection btw. Here is the html that displays the userlist:

```
<h1>User List</h1>
    <ul>
      <%
        var list = '';
        for (i = 0; i < userlist.length; i++) {
          if (userlist[i].deleted==false) {
            list += `<li><a href="userdetail/?uid="+${userlist[i].uid}" id="${i}"> ${userlist[i].username} </a></li>`;
          }
        }
      %>
      <%- list %>
    </ul>
```

Then I have in a .js file this bit that given the uid will return a doc with the correct userinfo

```
/*GET UserDetails page.*/ 
router.get('/userdetails', function(req, res) {
  var queryID = req.uid
  var db = req.db;
  var collection = db.get('usercollection');
  collection.find({"uid" : queryID},{},function(e,docs){
      res.render('userdetail', {
          "userinfo" : docs
      });
  });
});
```

I am, as my username says, out of my depth right now and would appreciate any guidance or even reading material that could help. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like just want to use `req.query.uid` as the `req.query` object automatically contains the parsed query string in Express.  You will need to make your URL match your route definition as one current uses `/userdetail` and the other uses `/userdetails`.  Also, put a `/` on front of the link you are generating so it is not page relative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

href attribute of the a tag was wrong. Try with this.

```js
list += `<li><a href="userdetail/?uid=${userlist[i].uid}" id="${i}"> ${userlist[i].username} </a></li>`;
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @Sophie! that did solve my dynamic url problem

Answer (score 0):

In your href, you're not using the template string properly.

Change this:

```
`<li><a href="userdetail/?uid="+${userlist[i].uid}" id="${i}"> ${userlist[i].username} </a></li>`;
```

to this:

```
`<li><a href="/userdetail?uid=${userlist[i].uid}" id="${i}"> ${userlist[i].username} </a></li>`;
```

You don't want to be trying to do string match in the middle of the template string and your quoting was messed up too.

---

And, then on your server, you can change this:

```
var queryID = req.uid
```

to this:

```
const queryID = req.query.uid
```

In Express, the `req.query` object is a parsed version of the query string so any query string parameters present in the URL will be properties of the `req.query` object.